# In WandaVision, where did Pietro get his powers?

Tags: plot-explanation, marvel-cinematic-universe, wandavision

[WandaVision S01E09 Finale](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt13778978/?ref_=ttep_ep9)
**Spoilers ahead....**

---

When Wanda's brother first came into the scene, some people thought that this Pietro is from another universe. He has the same power as actual Pietro AKA Quicksilver. Later, we come to know that this is not Wanda's brother and this Pietro is controlled by Agatha Harkness. In the season finale, we come to know that this Pietro is actually a real-life resident of Westview named Ralph, playing the part of Agnes' husband controlled by some some sort of necklace. Does Ralph have the power of Quicksilver, or is that given by Agatha?

Does Agatha have the ability to make someone powerful? What powers can Agatha give to someone?

Comment: Wasn't there already a question like this from a day or two ago? Seems that got deleted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But does this Ralph has the power of Quicksilver. Or is that given by Agatha.

It's clear that Ralph's "power" came from Agatha, presumably from the necklace that Agatha used to control him since he's a hired actor not a metahuman.

> Does Agatha has the ability to make someone powerful?

Well kind of. Agatha is a centuries old magic practitioner so the extent of her abilities in the MCU is undefined.

Clearly she is powerful but the extent of her abilities is unknown.

[In the comics she is somewhat different](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agatha_Harkness) (certainly she's shown as being much older) and her history with Wanda is extremely complex but how much of that will be explored in the MCU in the future is unknown if, indeed, they choose to do so.

Comment: But Pietro was different in "Avengers: Age of Ultron" and Wanda also went to the flashback as shown in the series earlier. Why she even accepted him as his brother? Firstly I thought it was a connection to the multiverse but it wasn't.

Comment: @SurajitDas It isn't really clear that Wanda accepted him as Pietro. She keeps questioning him in the Halloween episode.

Comment: @pboss3010 got it. that's why Pietro ignored all of her questions. thanks!

Comment: While he got power thanks to Agatha, I think she has subverted Wanda's reality warping spell - she wouldn't be able to do it all by herself.